# Creating SSIS packages using express editions

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2012, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

In production I have SQL Server 2008 R2. I want to create DTSX/SSIS packages but when I go to the Microsoft Express site ( https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx ) I'm not sure which studio will work.

Will "Express 2013 for Windows Desktop" work for my case? I already have "Express 2012 for Web" and SQL Server 2008 Management Studio installed locally so will that interfere?

Answer (score 1):

You will need the relevant version of SSDT (SQL Server Data Tools).  According to this page, if the latest version doesn't work, these older versions might:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674919.aspx